# How web3.eth subscription works?

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I tried code from [web3js docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#eth-subscription-return) , but it didnt woork for me. I dont get any logs. Any idea why?

code i used:

```
    var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('syncing', function(error, sync){
    if (!error)
        console.log(sync);
})
    .on("data", function(sync){
        console.log(sync);
    })
    .on("changed", function(isSyncing){
        if(isSyncing) {
            console.log("changed");
        } else {
            console.log("changed to false");
        }
    });
```

geth:

```
geth  --testnet --rpcapi "eth,web3, personal, accounts, miner, admin" --rpccorsdomain='*' --rpc --rpcaddr="0.0.0.0" --rpcport "8545" --ws --wsorigins="*" --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --fast
```

web3:

```
let web3 =  new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("ws://geth:8546"));
```

web3 version:

```
"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.30"
```

Blochchain is fully sinced.

Comment: I don't see you handling the error propperly, try with 
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('syncing', function(error, sync){
    if (error != null)
        console.log(error);
and report if any error appeared.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you will have to change    `"ws://geth:8546"`
because you are passing websocket when it is expecting an `HttpProvider`.

Try changing `.HttpProvider` to `.WebsocketProvider` :

```
 let web3 =  new Web3(new web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://geth:8546"));
```

Let me know if this worked out for you.